# Executable Crashing After Calling Function Thrice

Tags: c++, mingw, stringstream

I'd like to let it be known that I'm relatively new to C++ (and feeling slightly guilty for asking two questions on the same day pertaining to the same project).

---

Running the loop below (or uncommenting the five consecutive lines calling `MyDownloadFunction` then running), will cause an application crash.

Error Message:
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure' what(): basic_ios::clear
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.`

What I'd like to know is why it doesn't crash if the function is called only once or twice, but crashes if it is run 3 or more times (and on the third time, the file is saved properly) and, of course, how to fix it.

Please assume `https://MyWebsite.com` exists for this question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    typedef int * (*MyDownloadToUrl)(void*, const char*, const char*, DWORD, void*);
    HINSTANCE LibHnd = LoadLibrary("Urlmon.dll");
    MyDownloadToUrl MyDownloadFunction = (MyDownloadToUrl)GetProcAddress(LibHnd,"URLDownloadToFileA");

    stringstream URL;
    stringstream Iteration;

    // MyDownloadFunction(NULL, "https://google.ca", "Google 1.htm", 0, NULL);
    // MyDownloadFunction(NULL, "https://google.ca", "Google 2.htm", 0, NULL);
    // MyDownloadFunction(NULL, "https://google.ca", "Google 3.htm", 0, NULL);
    // MyDownloadFunction(NULL, "https://google.ca", "Google 4.htm", 0, NULL);
    // MyDownloadFunction(NULL, "https://google.ca", "Google 5.htm", 0, NULL);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        URL << "https://MyWebsite.com/" << i << "/";
        cout << URL.str() << "\r\n";

        Iteration << i << ".htm";
        cout << Iteration.str() << "\r\n\r\n";

        MyDownloadFunction(NULL, URL.str().c_str(), Iteration.str().c_str(), 0, NULL);

        URL.str("");
        Iteration.str("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URLDownloadToFile` (and most if not all other Windows API functions) uses the stdcall calling convention rather than the ccall convention.  Also the first and last parameter are not `void*`s, they are `LPUNKNOWN` and `LPBINDSTATUSCALLBACK`, and it returns a `HRESULT`, not an `int*`.  It is undefined behavior to call a function of one type through a pointer to a different type.  So you need to change your typedef to:

```
typedef HRESULT (__stdcall *MyDownloadToUrl)(LPUNKNOWN, const char*, const char*, DWORD, LPBINDSTATUSCALLBACK);
```

Comment: Changing the `typedef` to the line you provided causes many compiler problems. In addition, as far as I understand, `NULL` can be passed to a `void*` without problems (in the documentation, it tells us to use `NULL` when the status of a download is not required).

Comment: True using `void*` is probably maybe OK, but it is undefined behavior.  It could work perfectly or it could reformat your hard drive.  The language gives no guarantee of what will happen when you invoke UB.  That typedef works for me using Visual Studio 2010.  I've not used mingw much, but it looks like you may need to use `__stdcall` instead of `_stdcall`.